# Swift: to make this long code shorter

Tags: swift

I'm in way of making my first app in Swift which is Piano app.
and I somehow could make it!

but I'd like to know how I can make codes shorter.
I maybe have to use Array and Loop(?) and something, and searched by myself but couldn't get it.

I'd really appreciate if somebody can help.

Here is my "view controller.swift"

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var pianoSoundC3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("C3", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerC3 = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundCS = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("C#", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerCS = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundD = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("D", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerD = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundDS = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("D#", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerDS = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundE = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("E", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerE = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundF = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("F", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerF = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundFS = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("F#", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerFS = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundG = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("G", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerG = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundGS = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("G#", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerGS = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundA = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("A", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerA = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundAS = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("A#", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerAS = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundB = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("B", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerB = AVAudioPlayer()

var pianoSoundC4 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("C4", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayerC4 = AVAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    audioPlayerC3 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundC3, error: nil)
    audioPlayerC3.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerCS = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundCS, error: nil)
    audioPlayerCS.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerD = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundD, error: nil)
    audioPlayerD.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerDS = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundDS, error: nil)
    audioPlayerDS.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerE = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundE, error: nil)
    audioPlayerE.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerF = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundF, error: nil)
    audioPlayerF.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerFS = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundFS, error: nil)
    audioPlayerFS.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerG = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundG, error: nil)
    audioPlayerG.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerGS = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundGS, error: nil)
    audioPlayerGS.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerA = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundA, error: nil)
    audioPlayerA.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerAS = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundAS, error: nil)
    audioPlayerAS.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerB = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundB, error: nil)
    audioPlayerB.prepareToPlay()

    audioPlayerC4 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pianoSoundC4, error: nil)
    audioPlayerC4.prepareToPlay()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func C3(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerC3.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerC3.play()
}

@IBAction func CS(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerCS.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerCS.play()
}

@IBAction func D(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerD.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerD.play()
}

@IBAction func DS(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerDS.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerDS.play()
}

@IBAction func E(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerE.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerE.play()
}

@IBAction func F(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerF.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerF.play()
}

@IBAction func FS(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerFS.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerFS.play()
}

@IBAction func G(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerG.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerG.play()
}

@IBAction func GS(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerGS.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerGS.play()
}

@IBAction func A(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerA.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerA.play()
}

@IBAction func AS(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerAS.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerAS.play()
}

@IBAction func B(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerB.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerB.play()
}

@IBAction func C4(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayerC4.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayerC4.play()
}

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing working code. You may have better luck on codereview.stackexchange.com if you modify your question to fit their question requirements.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that and thank you.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Welcome to stack overflow. :-) We just get a lot of questions here that are more suited to websites like codereview.stackexchange.com or programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Seems stupid, this really should be a good question to ask here because the answer is not an optimization, and it speaks to the core of how to use the language, which if that's out of scope, this site is useless.

Comment: My recommendation would be to go look at the Enum examples in the free Swift book from Apple for Playing Cards. Do the same thing with the notes here.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I'm going to check Enum examples!